# No bitcode option in Xcode 7.1

Tags: xcode, app-store, bitcode

I'm trying to submit an app to Apple TV App Store. However iTunes Connect complains that it does not contain bitcode. But there is no bitcode option in the Xcode 7.1 build options.

Has anyone seen this before, and how do you fix it?

[image]

Comment: I have then option on xcode 7.1 7B91b http://i.imgur.com/r5JOFsZ.png Don't you have a search string in the top right corner ?

Answer (score 0):

Bitcode is required for all tvOS apps.
Enable Bitcode option does not appear for tvOS projects